# How to insert into a different collection in node/mongoose application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new, I created a database in mongodb and it has two collections, 'users' and another collection that is separate from 'users'.

Currently, I have an nodejs/express application that uses mongoose to enter a new entry into 'users'.

How can I use mongoose to enter a new entry into the other collection? Is it possible to switch collections?

Comment: You should show some of your code so we can understand the context better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose simplifies CRUD operations a lot.

You can create specific schemas and models that correspond to different collections in your db.

For example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

const otherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({/* config */});

const Other = mongoose.model('other', otherSchema);

// --- etc...
```

Then you perform different crud operations with the models you created.

See [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```js
user.find()......
separateUser.find()...
```